# How to conditionally set a css class with struts2

Tags: html, class, struts2

I need to display a sequence of `<tr>` elements with a `<struts:iterator>` tag and set a class of each `<tr>` conditionally.

Let's say I have a list `items = {1, 2a, 2b, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9a, 9b}`, and also two other lists `duplicates = {2b, 9b}` and `jumps = {6, 9a}`. How can I iterate over those items, display them in an HTML element and set a class of that element to `duplicate` and/or `jump` depending if the corresponding list contains that item?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can refer to [this website](http://www.vaannila.com/struts-2/struts-2-example/struts-2-iterator-tag-example1.html), it's detailing the iterator tag of Struts2

Comment: the given link by Nil is not available now. so i have added couple of other links for iterator tag in Nil's answer

Comment: This is why answering in one line with a link is a bad idea.

Answer (score -1):

You could add a method `boolean isDuplicated(String itemid)` to your action and code something as :

```
<s:iterator id="item"  value="items">
<tr <s:if test="isDuplicated(#item)"> class='duplicated' </s:if> >
```

You get the idea. You could even (though some purist might object that you put some presentation related code in you action) code a method that gives you the "class" of each item

```
<s:iterator id="item"  value="items">
<tr class='<s:property value="getClassForItemDuplicated(#item)" />'>
```